# Solr: Using a Filter Query on a boolean field?

Tags: solr

I have an indexed, stored Boolean field that I'm trying to use as a filter:

```
<field name="is_instrumental" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

However, when I try to use it as a fq parameter, the query returns zero results:

```
select?q=*:*&fq=is_instrumental:true&wt=xml&indent=true

<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <str name="q">*:*</str>
      <str name="wt">xml</str>
      <str name="fq">is_instrumental:true</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"></result>
</response>
```

I've tried every combination I can think of (true, false, 1, 0, TRUE, FALSE, also in quotes), no matter what I try it doesn't return anything.  Filters on other fields (ints or strings) work perfectly fine.  Using Solr 4.1.

What am I missing?

Edit:

solrconfig.xml: http://pastebin.com/kGWhQBma

schema.xml: http://pastebin.com/uqnYuuHR

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the `is_instrumental` field is being correctly populated for each item in the index?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes - I see things like <bool name="is_instrumental">false</bool> (or true) in the result when I make a normal query.

Comment: what data are you feeding into the Boolean field ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query syntax `&fq=is_instrumental:true` should work.

My guess here is that you are using a customized version of the /select request handler that is implementing a custom query parser like the [eDisMax (Extended Dismax)](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) Parser. Perhaps the `&uf` parameter has been set to prevent fielded searches. Can you check your solrconfig.xml and see how the defaults for the `<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">` configuration are defined?

Comment: I don't think I'm doing any of that, as far as I can tell.  It's mainly based on the default (tutorial) config files for Solr 4.1, and I'm running the query through the admin interface, without checking dismax or any other option.  I edited my question to include my solrconfig.xml and schema.xml.

Comment: Ok. I did not see anything in the configuration files that looked out of place. Have you tried clearing the index and reloading your data?

Comment: Ugh... I had, but just to make sure I dropped everything again, restarted Solr, and re-imported, now it works as expected.  Thanks for your help!